# How to print json array in angular

Tags: html, typescript, angular6

Here Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parse-object
Response format from REST API is

```
[{"id":123,"name":Test,"value":{"pass": true, "verified": true}}, {"id":435,"name":Test12,"value":{"pass": false, "verified": true}},]
```

```
<div *ngFor="let record of student.value">
  <ul *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(record)">
    <li>{{key}} :: {{record[key]}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Getting error ** Cannot read property 'value' of undefined **

```
<div *ngFor="let rec of student">
      <h2>{{rec.id}}</h2>
         <div *ngFor="let result of rec.value">
               <h4>  {{value.pass}} </h4>
          </div>
   </div>
```

getting Error object of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

**How to fix it?**

I expect the output as

```
ID : 123 Name : Test Pass : true [yes] verified : true
```

Comment: `student` is `undefined`

Comment: Defined in Typescript and Console.log(student) prints
[{"id":123,"name":Test,"value":{"pass": true, "verified": true}}, {"id":435,"name":Test12,"value":{"pass": false, "verified": true}},]

Comment: check `typeof student`

Comment: you need to parse the data

Comment: `this.student = JSON.parse(student)`

Comment: If you are doing this for debug reasons, I suggest you use the `json` pipe, which converts a value to its JSON-format representation. You could do this:  `{{ student | json }}`. The docs are here: https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

Comment: In my response value is in string format thats why it is not printing {{ value.pass}}

Answer (score 0):

You only need 1 `ngFor`, your value is not array.

```
<div *ngFor="let rec of student">
      <h2>Id: {{rec.id}} Name: {{rec.name}} Pass: {{rec.value.pass}} Verified: {{rec.value.verified}}</h2>
</div>
```

Reference (you can format it)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iterator

Updated:

Change your map function with JSON.parse like this

```
this.student = ["{pass: true, verified: true}", "{pass: false, verified: true}"];
    this.student = this.student.map(c=>JSON.parse(c.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+): ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/g, "\"$1\":\"$2\"")));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parse-object

Comment: Throwing error **SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 32
    at JSON.parse**

`this.http.get('/api/allreports/' + this.sid, options)
      .subscribe(result => {   
       var obj = result.json();
this.student = obj.map(c=>JSON.parse(c.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+): ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/g, "\"$1\":\"$2\"")));
});`

Comment: Did you check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parse-object ?

Comment: can you printout var obj or result here?

Comment: '[{"id":123,"name":Test,"value":"{pass: true,verified: true}"}, {"id":435,"name":Test12,"value":"{pass: false, verified: true}"},]'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191310/discussion-between-narendar-and-hien-nguyen).

Comment: where do i need to changes to fix this issue.

Comment: can you update your API? because it return "name":Test, and it can not parse to JSON object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55723951/keyvalue-giving-odd-output

Answer (score 0):

I just write a basic `ngFor` code using your **Student Array**. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

**HTML**

```
<div class="studentList" *ngFor="let student of students">
  <ul>
    <li>ID : {{student.id}}</li>
    <li>Name : {{student.name}}</li>
    <li>Pass : {{student.value.pass}} [{{student.value.pass ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}]</li>
    <li>Verified : {{student.value.verified}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
students = [
{
  "id":123,
  "name":"Test",
  "value":{"pass": true, "verified": true}
}, {
  "id":435,
  "name":"Test12",
  "value":{"pass": false, "verified": true}
  }
]
```

**CSS**

```
.studentList ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.studentList ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the link. Thanks

Comment: yes @Hassan how iterate over object as type string and display values

Comment: any inputs to how to iterate

Comment: There are few extra quotes in your student array and what exactly you want to do in your .map method ?