# Keyvalue pipe using to print nested values

Tags: angular, angular6

Here my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vj4llg

To print nested array values, I am using Keyvalue pipe

```
<p>Use keyvalue pipe</p>
<ul *ngFor="let stdObj of student">
    <li>ID : {{stdObj.id}} Name : {{stdObj.name}}
        <ng-container *ngFor="let test of stdObj?.value | keyvalue">
            {{test.key}} : {{test.value}}
        </ng-container>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In typescript

```
 this.student = [
      {
        id:123,
        name: "Test",
        value:["{pass: true,verified: true}"]
      }, 
      {
        id:435,
        name:"Test12",
        value:["{pass: false, verified: true}"]
      }
    ]
```

Expecting ouput as

`ID : 123 Name : Test pass : true verified : true`

Answer (score 0):

Currently by your definition, value key holds an array of string: ["{...}"], so the output for it will not show what you expected; instead, it will output index value 0 as 'key' value for the first item, while "{...}' as its value.

So in order to get what you expected, re-defined value as below:

```
value: {pass: true,verified: true}
```

Comment: what you said is right but how to convert a response of REST API